# Adding square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I forgot how to add square roots, can someone please show me what I'm supposed to do? Example:

Add
$\sqrt{8} + \sqrt{32}$

I did:

$\sqrt{8} = \sqrt{4}\sqrt{2}$

$\sqrt{32} = \sqrt{4}\sqrt{8}$

$(\sqrt{4}\sqrt{2}) + (\sqrt{2}\sqrt{8})$

I just get lost here, I don't even know if what I did is right.

Comment: Use $8=4\times2$, $32=16\times2$.

Comment: To add square roots, the "insides" must be the same $A\sqrt{B} + C\sqrt{B} = (A+C) \sqrt{B}$. You treat it like adding coefficients for like-terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{32}=\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{4\times8}=\sqrt{8}+2\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{8}=6\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I edited due to some typos I had. it's all good now.

Comment: That was certainly not a typo but a silly mistake! :)

Comment: @hawk Yes you could say. I was going too quick and messed up some addition.

Comment: How did sqrt4 * 8 because 2sqrt8?

Comment: $\sqrt{a*b}=\sqrt{a}*\sqrt{b}$. That's what I used to separate it so in your case it would be: $\sqrt{4*8}=\sqrt{4}*\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{8}$. And for the 8 you do same thing.

Comment: but 2 * 8 is 16, and 4 * 8 is 32. How can they be equal? Did you simplify the 4?

Comment: @Rajesh $2*8$ and $2\sqrt{8}$ are two different things.

Comment: I see no logical progression from them though, how did you get the $2\sqrt{8}$?

Comment: @Rajesh $$\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{32}=\sqrt{4*2}+\sqrt{4*8}=2\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{4*2}=2\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{2}=6\sqrt{2}$$ I hope this clears things up for you. It can't get any clearer than that.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt8+\sqrt{32}=\sqrt8(1+\sqrt4)=2\sqrt2(1+2)=6\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{32}$

= $\sqrt{2\times2^2}+\sqrt{2\times2^4} $  { Jus split the 8 and write even powers of 2 separate }

= $2\sqrt{2} + 2^2\sqrt2$ {as $\sqrt2^2 = 2$ and $\sqrt2^4 = 2^2 $ }

= $2\sqrt{2} + 4\sqrt2$  {$as  2^2 = 4$}

= $\sqrt{2} (2 + 4)$

= $\sqrt{2} (6)$ {similar to writing $\sqrt{2}\times (6)$}

= $6\sqrt{2}$

Hope, I made it as simplified as possible.